How to pass JSON body with angular16 to API?
I am have problem understanding how to pass email variable from frontend to backend API.
in backend API i have a method to add new subscription record:
        [HttpPost("save")]
        [Authorize]
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveNewsLetterSubscription(NewsletterDto newsletterDto)
        {
            var callRequest = mapper.Map<Newsletter>(newsletterDto);

            uow.messageRepository.AddMessage(callRequest);
            await uow.SaveAsync();
            return Ok(callRequest);
        }

this is working in postman after adding authorization Bearer and also JSON record of Email.
postman
now in frontend I have a service:
subscribeEmail(email: string)
  {
    const theEmail = JSON.stringify(email);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')
      })
    };
      return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/message/save', {httpOptions});
  }

and I am not sure how to pass the variable "theEmail" to the API in the code above?
in my TS file I have called the service:
 showMenu()
  {
    this.alert.getSubscriber();

    setTimeout(async () =>
      {
        this.theEmail = localStorage.getItem("email");

        //this will save the email to subscribers list in db
        this.housingService.subscribeEmail(this.theEmail).subscribe();

        emailjs.init("IclaYU2yrPjG2MHfm");
          
          let response = await emailjs.send("service_ytxrv42","template_6j13ark",{
            to_name: "Admin",
            user_name: "User",
            user_email: this.theEmail,
            subject: "Subscription",
            message: "New subscription!",
            });

            this.alert.success("You have subscribed successfully!");
            
      }, 10000);

      setTimeout(() =>
        {
          window.location.reload();
        }, 15000);
  }

the code above should run the service and add the email record to the database but it is not doing so as I am not sure how to pass the email to the API. the email is sent successfully but the data is not saved in the DB.

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/message/save', {httpOptions});
where do you add the email? should probably be return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/message/save', theEmail,  {httpOptions});

I had to add it as JSON format:
const theEmail = {'Email': email};

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
  })
};
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/message/save', theEmail, httpOptions);

